# Filtering data with CriteriaBuilder to compare enum values with literals not working

Tags: java, enums, jpa

I have a java class with a enum field,

```
org.example.Importacion {
...
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private EstadoImportacion estadoImportacion;

  public static enum EstadoImportacion {
      NOT_VALID, IMPORTED, ERROR, VALID
  }

}
```

When I create a Query with CriteriaBuilder and I try to compare the enum values, one from a filter to the criteriabuilder using literals, the final result of the query does not filter the enum values, so if I send org.example.Importacion.EstadoImportacion.ERROR to the  iterator method, the rersult will not filter ERROR on the filnal result list.

The companyCod filters ok, so If I send "COMPANY001" as a companyCode, the querybuilder filters the final result.

I would like to know how to compare enums in the query:

```
   public Iterator<Importacion> iterator (
     long first, 
     long count, 
     String companyCod, 
     org.example.Importacion.EstadoImportacion estado) {

    CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Importacion> criteria = cb.createQuery(Importacion.class);
    Root<Importacion> desembolso = criteria.from(Importacion.class);
    criteria.select(desembolso);
    Predicate p = cb.conjunction();
    if(companyCod != null) {

        p = cb.and(p, cb.equal(desembolso.get("codigo"), companyCod));
        //This part works fine!
    }


    if (estado != null) {
        Expression<org.example.Importacion.EstadoImportacion> estadoImportacion = null;

        if (estado.equals(org.example.Importacion.EstadoImportacion.ERROR)) {
            estadoImportacion = cb.literal(org.example.Importacion.EstadoImportacion.ERROR);
        }

        if (estado.equals(org.example.Importacion.EstadoImportacion.IMPORTED)) {
            estadoImportacion = cb.literal(org.example.Importacion.EstadoImportacion.IMPORTED);
        }

        if (estado.equals(org.example.Importacion.EstadoImportacion.NOT_VALID)) {
            estadoImportacion = cb.literal(org.example.Importacion.EstadoImportacion.NOT_VALID);
        }

        if (estado.equals(org.example.Importacion.EstadoImportacion.VALID)) {
            estadoImportacion = cb.literal(org.example.Importacion.EstadoImportacion.VALID);
        }

        p = cb.and(p, cb.equal(estadoImportacion, cb.literal(estado)));
    //Doesn't seems to compare enum values

    }

    criteria.where(p);
    javax.persistence.Query query = em.createQuery(criteria);

    query.setMaxResults((int)count + (int)first + 1);
    query.setFirstResult((int)first);
    List resultList = query.getResultList();
    Iterator iterator = (Iterator) resultList.iterator();
    LOGGER.info("desembolso size: {}", resultList.size());
    return iterator;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your criteria compares a literal with the enum. That's not what you want. You want to compare the Importacion's estadoImportacion with the given estado:

```
Predicate p = cb.conjunction();
if(companyCod != null) {
    p = cb.and(p, cb.equal(desembolso.get("codigo"), companyCod));
}
if (estado != null) {
    p = cb.and(p, cb.equal(desembolso.get("estadoImportacion"), estado));
}
```